# Fragment replacing problems

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having issues with fragment replacing implementing a navigation drawer.

The problem is layout overlapping, but it happens only if I let the application on the background for a long time (I asume after the activity goes to Stop).

This is the code I'm using for changing fragments. I'm not doing anything in onStop method
 (Should I be doing something?)

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        if(lastPosition == position){
            return;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment lastFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( lastTag );
        Fragment fragment;
        if ( lastFragment != null ) {
            transaction.hide( lastFragment );
        }

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                lastTag = "miPerfil";
                lastPosition = 0;
                fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("miPerfil");
                if(fragment != null) {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                transaction.add(R.id.container, MiPerfilFragment.newInstance(position + 1),"miPerfil");

                break;
            case 1:
                lastTag = "misReportes";
                lastPosition = 1;
                fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("misReportes");
                if(fragment != null) {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                transaction.add(R.id.container, MisReportesFragment.newInstance(position + 1),"misReportes");

                break;
            case 2:
                lastTag = "mapFragment";
                lastPosition = 2;
                fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
                if(fragment != null) {
                    transaction.show(fragment);
                }else{
                    transaction.add(R.id.container, MapFragment.newInstance(position + 1),"mapFragment");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return;
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack( lastTag ).commit();
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is two solution that you can try to overcome from your problem of overlapping fragment.

try (1) set a background color to your fragment in xml file.

if it does not work,

try  (2) fixing this by writing your own code to remove any existing fragments before committing a new one.

for example:

```
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    mbFragment = new SettingsManageBooksFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.setting_detail_container2, mbFragment).commit();
    mImgFragmentTitle.setImageResource(R.drawable.manage_my_books);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageButtonSettingsManageBooks:

        if (mPurchaseHistory == true) {
            ft.remove(phFragment);

            Log.d(TAG, "REMOVING PURCHASE HISTORY FRAG");

        } else if (mAudio == true) {
            ft.remove(aFragment);

            Log.d(TAG, "REMOVING AUDIO FRAG");
        } else if (mRestore == true) {
            ft.remove(rFragment);

            Log.d(TAG, "REMOVING RESTORE FRAG");
        } else if (mCopyright == true) {
            ft.remove(cFragment);

            Log.d(TAG, "REMOVING COPYRIGHT FRAG");
        } else if (mAbout == true) {
            ft.remove(abFragment);

            Log.d(TAG, "REMOVING ABOUT FRAG");
        }
        ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mbFragment = new SettingsManageBooksFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.setting_detail_container2, mbFragment).commit();
        mImgFragmentTitle.setImageResource(R.drawable.manage_my_books);
        mManageBooks = true;
        mPurchaseHistory = false;
        mAudio = false;
        mRestore = false;
        mCopyright = false;
        mAbout = false;

        break;
```

hope it will helps....

if you use first solution You may also come up with problems where the fragment behind your new fragment is still clickable. If this happens then just make the parent view of the new fragment clickable..